# R how to fix error non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r

I am using R to do some integration.

If I have a function f(x)=x :`f<-function(x) return(x)`

And I make a function g(x) to calculate its integral like this:

`g<-function(x) return(integrate(f,0,x))` .

Then I make a third function h(x) to deal with the result I get from the g(x) :

`h<-function(x) {g(x)+1+2}` But I always get the error message "Error in g(x)+1+2 : non-numeric argument to binary operator"
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`integrate` does not return a number, it returns an object of class `integrate`, which also tells you some details about the numerical error, etc. See `?integrate`::Value

This can be seen by running `class(g(2))`.

You have to use `g(x)$value` to extract the value:

```
h <- function(x) g(x)$value + 1 + 2
```

I knew `g(x)` can be treated like a `list` and to extract `value` by using `dput`:

```
dput(g(2))

# structure(list(value = 2, abs.error = 2.22044604925031e-14, 
#                subdivisions = 1L,  message = "OK", 
#                call = integrate(f = f, lower = 0, upper = x)),
#           .Names = c("value", "abs.error", "subdivisions", 
#                      "message", "call"),
#           class = "integrate")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the *value* from the integral, not the integral object itself.  If you type:

```
> class(integrate(f, 0, 3))
[1] "integrate"
```

you will notice that the type is `integrate`.  This is the source of the `non-numeric argument` error you have been getting.

The following definition should work for you:

```
h <- function(x) { g(x)$value + 1 + 2 }
```